# Python file immediately closes

Tags: python-3.x, file

As an assignment for one of my classes, the professor had us download a file containing python code as well as a couple of text files that the python code will analyze.

The problem is, when I click to open the python file, the command window opens, then immediately closes. I can get it to stop from closing if I click on it fast enough, but that stops the code from loading, and any keystroke causes it to close again.

It's the same file every other student downloaded and used with no issue. I've tried re-downloading the file, re-installing python, even trying on a different computer. I've also tried opening it by entering the path file name in the command window with no success. Also no luck trying it in Jupyter Notebook or CodeLab. (And of course, no luck experimenting with the slew of possible solutions on previous Stack Overflow, Reddit, etc. questions).

Any ideas on the potential cause and/or solution?

Edit: cause unknown, but the solution was opening the file with Sypder console.

Comment: If you are clicking on an icon, the problem is probably that the code completes before you have time to see any output. It is somewhat complicated to enumerate all of the alternatives, but as a quick fix edit the file to include the line `input("Press enter to exit")` as the vary last line in the file.

Comment: Try running python filename in a command prompt and see if it runs then.

Comment: Try running it from the cmd prompt: `python MyScript.py` so you can see any errors that occur.

Comment: Don't run your programs by clicking on the file

Comment: As I said in my original post, I tried running it from the command prompt, and can't edit the document since it closes out immediately.

Comment: Then try right clicking and opening it with a text editor.

Comment: I'm not sure if some of these responses were meant to be condescending, or if it's just that no one read what I wrote very closely.

Answer (score 0):

the file closes immediately because It ended and returned 0, to stop that from happening you can add at the end of the python code something like that:
ending = input("press key to exit")
or just import time and use
time.sleep(5)
you can open your file in the cmd/terminal window and you will be able to see the results

Comment: As I said in my original post, that wouldn't be an option since I can't access the code in the first place.

Comment: I also had attempted to add that I found the solution to my problem (which was opening it in the Spyder console) but SO rejected the edit citing it was "superfluous and unhelpful." lol...

Comment: Open terminal/cmd get to the directory where you have downloaded the python files and use python "name of your file here.py" (or use python3 if you have more than one python version installed on your machine)